# How can you match on wildcard object keys using Jest matchers?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, wildcard, matcher

Presume that you have this value, where you can't predict the value of the keys in `foo`:

```js
{
  context: { version: 1.0 },
  value: {
    foo: {
      afh34q2: [1n, 100n],
    }
  }
}
```

How can I write a strict matcher that treats the keys as wildcards and asserts on the values only?

```js
expect(value).toStrictEqual({
  context: expect.objectContaining({
    version: expect.any(String),
  }),
  value: {
    foo: /* how to match on only the object values? */
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to describe in a single assertion the object containing dynamic keys, probably because if you define the assertion like this

```js
// ... 
foo: expect.objectContaining({ [expect.any(String)]: [1n, 100n] })
```

there wouldn't be a way do define the matcher object with multiple keys, amount of expected keys or the different possible values.

So what I would do is write a separate assertion on the `value.foo` property like this

```js
    test('should have string keys and number array values', () => {
        expect(Object.entries(value.value.foo)).toEqual([
            [expect.any(String), [1, 100]]
        ]);
    });
```

[repl.it example](https://replit.com/@esteterrez/jest-playground#sum.test.js)